# MongoDB authentication in a cluster

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I managed to configure a MongoDB cluster with authentication. By that I mean I activated the *authorization: enabled* on all *mongod* in my data replica set and on all *mongod* in the configuration replica set using the localhost exception mechanism.
My problem is with *mongos* now. When I start a *mongos* instance I have several errors regarding authentication like these ones:

```
[replSetDistLockPinger] pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: Unauthorized: not authorized on config to execute command { findAndModify: "lockpings", query: { _id: "as-nscl-01:27017:1475328403:-980595768" }, update: { $set: { ping: new Date(1476088485351) } }, upsert: true, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 15000 }, maxTimeMS: 30000 }
[UserCacheInvalidator] An error occurred while fetching current user cache generation to check if user cache needs invalidation: Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { _getUserCacheGeneration: 1, maxTimeMS: 30000 }
```

My problem is that I don't know what to do now. I don't see anything related to this in the documentation. Maybe I need to create a special user for *mongos* with some rights ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make it work. In fact, the problem was from the configuration file which was declaring *security.authorization: enabled*. This parameter is forbidden for a *mongos* instance and it was preventing the daemon to start. Removing the parameter solves the problem.
The errors I had was from previous runs.